# Can someone explain the mat4.translate function from glMatrix?

Tags: matrix, webgl, vector-graphics

Does anyone know why glmatrix ( 1.x ) defines mat4.translate like this:

```
/**
 * Translates a matrix by the given vector
 *
 * @param {mat4} mat mat4 to translate
 * @param {vec3} vec vec3 specifying the translation
 * @param {mat4} [dest] mat4 receiving operation result. If not specified result is written to mat
 *
 * @returns {mat4} dest if specified, mat otherwise
 */
mat4.translate = function (mat, vec, dest) {
    var x = vec[0], y = vec[1], z = vec[2],
        a00, a01, a02, a03,
        a10, a11, a12, a13,
        a20, a21, a22, a23;

    if (!dest || mat === dest) {
        mat[12] = mat[0] * x + mat[4] * y + mat[8] * z + mat[12];
        mat[13] = mat[1] * x + mat[5] * y + mat[9] * z + mat[13];
        mat[14] = mat[2] * x + mat[6] * y + mat[10] * z + mat[14];
        mat[15] = mat[3] * x + mat[7] * y + mat[11] * z + mat[15];
        return mat;
    }

    a00 = mat[0]; a01 = mat[1]; a02 = mat[2]; a03 = mat[3];
    a10 = mat[4]; a11 = mat[5]; a12 = mat[6]; a13 = mat[7];
    a20 = mat[8]; a21 = mat[9]; a22 = mat[10]; a23 = mat[11];

    dest[0] = a00; dest[1] = a01; dest[2] = a02; dest[3] = a03;
    dest[4] = a10; dest[5] = a11; dest[6] = a12; dest[7] = a13;
    dest[8] = a20; dest[9] = a21; dest[10] = a22; dest[11] = a23;

    dest[12] = a00 * x + a10 * y + a20 * z + mat[12];
    dest[13] = a01 * x + a11 * y + a21 * z + mat[13];
    dest[14] = a02 * x + a12 * y + a22 * z + mat[14];
    dest[15] = a03 * x + a13 * y + a23 * z + mat[15];
    return dest;
};
```

It looks like the vector values are multiplied (scaled) by the directional vectors ( dir, left, up ) of the matrix. But I don't understand why. Also why is mat[15] assigned. I thought it should always be 1...

I am using this most of the time and I am quite happy:

```
mat4.translate_alt = function (mat, vec, factor) {
            factor = factor || 1;
        mat[12] += vec[0]*factor;
        mat[13] += vec[1]*factor;
        mat[14] += vec[2]*factor;
    }
```

When should I use mat4.translate and when is my mat4.translate_alt enough ?

Answer (score 2):

`mat4.translate` translates a matrix with a given vector (vec3), which is the same as multiplying with a translation matrix.

Another way to look at it is to say `mat4.translate = mat4.multiply(someMatrix, mat4.create_translate_matrix(someVec3))` (pseudo-code).

Comment: You first sentence makes sense to me. But translate_alt does not create a translate matrix, it changes the x,y & z values of an existing matrix that can have rotations as well. What is the benefit of using the original translate function ? Thinking about it, it seems to me that the code applies the translation to the local coordinate system of the matrix, where as my function applies it to the world coordinate system.